# WKErrorDomain error 4 from WKWebView when calling existing JSFunction

Tags: javascript, swift, wkwebview

No matter what I do, I can't call this js function successfully without generating error.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getmessage() {
        //$('#discussion').append('<li>dummy</li>');
    }
    $(function () {
        var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
        chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (message) {
            var encodedMsg = $('<div />').text(message).html();
            $('#discussion').append('<li>' + encodedMsg + '</li>');
        };
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                chat.server.send($('#message').val());
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

error: WKErrorDomain code; 4

I have made sure that I inherit WKNavigaitonDelegate, set view as it's delegate and calling it from didFinishNavigation

Note that I can execute new js blocks just fine from my swift code with no issues, but when calling that existing function, it doesn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Safari Web Inspector](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) to get more information about what is going wrong.

You can enable it by making sure the developer menu is enabled.

[image: Show Developer Menu in Menu Bar]

After the simulator starts your app, you can go to `Developer->Simulator->[Your Page]`. Once the Web Inspector is open you can refresh your web view and you should see a "console error". This should give you more insight into your "JavaScript exception".

Comment: truly insightful! It said: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: getmessage
Should I start a new thread to ask about this question!?

Comment: Yip, and add a screenshot of what you see in the inspector. Perhaps a gist of you HTML code too.